# Is there a way to set your monitor to any arbitrary resolution and aspect ratio (like 1000x400, etc.)?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, resolution

I have a customer with a very very wide screen (1366 x 768) and I can reproduce the symptom using Virtual PC because I can resize the virtual PC window to get something close to that resolution.

But I'm trying to set the same conditions on my development PC and having no luck. I only get a set or preset aspect ratios.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but 1366x768 is 16:9 aspect ratio which is not really "very very wide". It actually seems to be the most common aspect ratio these days (on brand new machines). That said, this seems like more of a superuser question to me.

Comment: 16:9 is as wide as they come, I'm seeing a lot of 16:10 instead. The old standard was 4:3 (16:12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entech Taiwan](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/) makes a product, [PowerStrip](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) (sharewhare), that does that.  Or else you can try manually editing your registry, like [these directions](http://www.mp3car.com/vbulletin/lcd-display/42122-tutorial-forcing-custom-resolution-windows.html) show.  (I've not tried that personally, so where knows if it will work).

Although you could just set your application's window so it always opens to 1366x768 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

rdesktop lets you specify resolution when you connect through RDP:

```
 `rdesktop -g 1336x768 myhost`
```

So if your application works through remote desktop you can give it a try.

There is a [version for Win32](http://www.atomice.com/blog/?page_id=9)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by going to Display Properties, Advanced, Monitor Tab, and uncheck the "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display".  This will let you choose some other options for the resolution.

Answer (score -1):

open RDP file in notepad++ and change the resolution manually. before this change display setting to do not open in fullscreen